# sticky thead when table is fit-content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a page which consists of some header information on the top and a table below it. The header is expanded onLoad and the table is set to a max-height of 500px. This table will then be scrollable by default and its thead is sticky.

However, there's an option to collapse this header div, which then sets the table's max-height to fit-content. Now, the whole page is scrollable instead of just the table. Problem is, the thead is no longer sticky.

```
$("#table").css({ "max-height": "500px" });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3k2vnqyh/ is an simple example. Notice the thead is sticky when you scroll, then click the button which hides the div and gets rid of the table's scroll and makes the page scrollable instead, but also gets rid of the sticky thead. I'm just trying to unconditionally have the thead remain sticky. I'm using Chrome btw.

This seems to be a popular topic. I've tried solving it with css by using a variation of making the thead and "tds of the thead" have sticky positions and other attributes. But no dice. I'm using Bootstrap too.

Any ideas

Comment: Could you add [a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Added an example of my issue. I noticed removing the overflows for my table resolves things. However, it does not do that for my app